# how to set enviroment variable in docker

Tags: docker, go, makefile

High level- i have front end web application which runs on one docker container and i made second container for database mysql.
I picked a environment variable `mysqldb` i need to set that variable to ip address of  Docker MySQL container. Part two- i got web application which has to know what ip address is running on( mysql container whatever its going to be because the ip of the container will change) so it has to read that environment variable that was set. So my question do i set a variable so when i run the program mysql container runs and shows that database i set up is working

Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.19-bullseye AS build     
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./ ./
RUN go build -o main ./

FROM debian:bullseye
COPY --from=build /app/main /usr/local/bin/main
#CMD[apt-get install mysql-clientmy]
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/main"]
```

makefile

```
build:
    go build -o bin/main main.go
    
run:
    go run main.go
runcontainer:
    docker run -d -p  9008:8080 tiny


compile:
    echo "Compiling for every OS and Platform"
    GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm go build -o bin/main-linux-arm main.go
    GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm64 go build -o bin/main-linux-arm64 main.go
    GOOS=freebsd GOARCH=386 go build -o bin/main-freebsd-386 main.go
```

part of my go program

```
func main() {

    linkList = map[string]string{}

    http.HandleFunc("/link", addLink)
    http.HandleFunc("/hpe/", getLink)
    http.HandleFunc("/", Home)

    ip := flag.String("i", "0.0.0.0", "")
    port := flag.String("p", "8080", "")
    flag.Parse()
    fmt.Printf("Listening on %s \n", net.JoinHostPort(*ip, *port))
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(net.JoinHostPort(*ip, *port), nil))
}
```

Comment: If both the application and database are in containers, you'd typically attach both to the same Docker network, and use the containers' names or Compose service names as host names.  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation is one overview.  You pretty much never need the container-private IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieved this by using env variable in Dockerfile or Docker compose file. By the way don't use IP of db container. Always use hostname. Hostname is static but every recreation of container IP will be get changed.

Comment: How the example of this will be?can you demostrate it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the following way in the Dockerfile itself(The example itself if from the Docker documentation):

```
FROM busybox
ENV FOO=/bar
WORKDIR ${FOO}   # WORKDIR /bar
ADD . $FOO       # ADD . /bar
COPY \$FOO /quux # COPY $FOO /quux
```

In case of a Docker-compose file, you can try to do the following:

```yaml
version:'3'
services:
  mysqldb:
    container_name: mydb
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - db.env
```

You should change it according to your requirements.

`Addendum`:

As far as I can understand what you're trying to achieve, and you can solve this problem by using a `db_env` in your go program structure as well as your docker-compose file.

Try to do the following:

- create a .env file in your go project structure,
- add `HOST=172.0.0.1`
- Read the variable in your go program using either a third party package like `viper` or simply using `os.Getenv("HOST")`

create a docker-compose file and add both the services you're supposed to create.
You can look at the example that I provided earlier and then create services accordingly by specifying the same `db_env` below the docker-compose `env_file` flag.

Comment: `FROM busybox
ENV mysql=/bar
WORKDIR ${mysql}   # WORKDIR /bar
ADD . $mysql       # ADD . /bar
COPY \$mysql  /quux # COPY $sql /quux`
so like this and how does this know to run make new container for database. Im confused im sorry im new to this.

Comment: Are you trying to create two separate containers? One for your frontend and second for your database?

Comment: yes so If you look at the file code above i already have one container running(tiny) that is a frontend and for backend i need set enviroment variable so when i run program it creates mysql db container with ip adress(which always could be different) of the container because right now from tiny container im manually  connecting using this command `mysql -u root -p -h 172.0.0.2`

Comment: ip adress changes that is why i need set a env variable then call that from go program

Comment: Are you trying to use an ENV_VARIABLE for the go program or the Dockerfile? Can you kindly break down your query into small pieces, so each thing can be achieved one by one?

Comment: first part-create environment variable that is going to set to ip address of mysql container.
part two: my go application need to know what ip address my sql server is running on.(whatever is going to be)it has to read that env  variable that was set when we did the docker run command..i think ineed use somelike get.env function or something like

Comment: bassicaly when i run go program the log supposed to say oh your backend db container is runing on this ip. I know im pretty bad of exlaning things.

Comment: You mean in the go program itself? You don't want to specify the ip address, but rather specify the ip-address in the ENV_VARIABLE and use that variable in the go program, right?

Comment: because everytime some user runs this program the ip address/port number changes of the container for sql. and yes so basicaly when i run the program log should print out your container ipadress and port number is this..

Comment: i wish i could just show you my whole code and how im running it

Comment: As far as I can understand what you're trying to achieve, and you can solve this problem by using an `db_env` in your go program structure as well as your docker-compose file.

Try to do the following:
- create a .env file in your go project structure, 
- add HOST=172.0.0.1

create a docker-compose file and add both the services you're supposed to run.
You can look at the example that I provided earlier and then create services accordingly by specifying the same `db_env` below the docker-compose `env_file` flag.

Comment: I'll try to add this as an answer so, it's properly formatted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249501/discussion-between-mostlycryptic-and-tank92).